# Wrong port on startup (recvfrom)

Tags: c, linux, dns, udp, port

I have stumbled upon a strange behaviour while writing a small DNS server and striped it to a minimum. This program should listen on 127.0.0.1:1337 for DNS queries and reply with a deny. I test its behaviour by issuing `dig @localhost -p 1337 foo.bar.` If line 48 is commented out `//char bout[bufferSize];  // <-- WTF` it works like charm.

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static int SOCKET;


void bindSocket(){
    int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not create socket\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    memset((char *)&address, 0, sizeof(address));

    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr);
    address.sin_family  = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port    = htons(1337);

    int rc = bind ( s, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof (address) );
    if (rc < 0) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Could not bind Socket\n %s \n", strerror(errno));
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SOCKET = s;
}

void decline(uint16_t err, char *bin, struct sockaddr *to){
    char bout[12];
    memset((bout + 4), 0, 8);
    memcpy(bout, bin, 4);
    bout[2] = (bout[2] | 0x80) & 0xFE;
    bout[3] = (bout[3] | err ) & 0x7F;
    sendto( SOCKET, bout, 12, 0, to, sizeof(struct sockaddr) );
}

void hereBeDragons(){
    size_t bufferSize = 512;
    char bin[bufferSize];
    char bout[bufferSize]; // <-- WTF
    struct sockaddr sender;
    socklen_t len;
    while(1){
        memset(bin,  0, bufferSize);
        int n = recvfrom( SOCKET, bin, bufferSize, 0, &sender, &len );
        if (n < 0) continue;
        puts("receved a query");

        /* Strictly decline all invalid queries */
        decline( 2, bin, &sender);
    }
}

int main(){
    bindSocket();
    hereBeDragons();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

program output:

```
received a query
```

dig output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> @localhost -p 1337 foo.bar.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 37520
;; flags: qr ad; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#1337(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Aug 29 21:37:46 CEST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 12
```

This is just a cut down example, in the real code bout is used to construct a valid response to the incoming queries. But when I leave it in, the following proplem appears:

[image: Wireshark packet capture]

the program sends the answer to the wrong port, after 5 seconds dig retries and the program sends to the right port.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not using bout in the function then why bothering to initialize it??? Or is it a different code??

Comment: Code that forms part of a question must be included in the question, not posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very subtle bug.

The socket address length parameter, the sixth parameter to recvfrom(), must be initialized. It must be set to indicate the length of the address buffer passed in the fifth parameter. When recvfrom() returns, the length is updated to reflect the actual size of the network address structure written to it.

Before the call to recvfrom(), add:

```
len=sizeof(sender);
```

This is explained in the [recvfrom(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom):

> The argument addrlen is a value-result argument, which the caller
>   should initialize before the call to the size of the buffer associated
>   with src_addr, and modified on return to indicate the actual size of
>   the source address

Comment: Aren't _srcaddr_ and _addrlen_ the 5th and 6th parameters of `recvfrom`, not the 3rd and 4th?

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken -- edited to make that correction.

Comment: wow, my man page is outdated. Thank you for the answer, unfortunately i can't upvote jet.